# Firefox input type time text-align: center

Tags: html, css, firefox, input, text-align

i want to align the text of an input type time in Firefox.
The following code works in Chrome and Edge but not Firefox:

```
<input type="time" value="00:00">

input {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/Teiem/pen/BaBzmwY)

Comment: Maybe Firefox is simply not capable of centering a time input?

Comment: @UweKeim that would explain the <5% browser market share for Firefox.

Comment: Here in Germany, Firefox has still an outstanding [approx. 15% market share](https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/all/germany).

Comment: It's probably the same case as `<input type="file">` elements: it's a widget that may have any design implementations can conceive so not all CSS properties apply.

Comment: BTW, it doesn't answer this specific question but I found this interesting gist: [Styling native elements](https://gist.github.com/webtobesocial/aefd6e25064c08e0cc9a)

Answer (score 1):

Even not the exactly solution, you can try to use a `<div>` element as the parent of `<input>` element and use CSS for centering that `<div>` element such as below. It will work on both Firefox and Chrome.

```html
<div class="center">
  <input type="time" value="00:00">
</div>
```

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that would accomplish the same result. Place the input inside of a div and a center the div's text. The following results in a consistent display on Chrome, Edge, and Firefox :

```css
input {
    border: none;
}

.container {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <input type="time" value="00:00">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Working on any Browser.

```
<div style = "text-align: center; width: 100px; padding: 50px;">
  <input type="time" value="00:00">
</div>
```

In Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <input type="time" value="00:00">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```